# Odds of 9 diamonds from 8 ore with fortune 3?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Title. It caught my attention becuase I dont think I've ever gotten this unlucky lol

What's the odds of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fortune#Ore):

> Fortune III gives a chance to multiply drops by 2, 3, or 4 (20% (1⁄5) chance each, averaging 120% (11⁄5) increase).

You get 9 diamonds from 8 ore if you get an x2 bonus on one of the ores and no bonus on the others. This by itself, happens with a probability of 1/5 * (2/5)^7 = 128/390625.

This probability then needs to be multiplied by 8 because there are 8 different cases (of which ore gets the bonus), giving 1024/390625, or about 0.26%.

Comment: the odds of getting 1 with fortune 3 are supposedly 40%, so wouldnt it be 0.4 x 0.4 x 0.4 x 0.4 x 0.4 x 0.4 x 0.4 x 0.4?

Comment: That would be the odds of getting 8 diamonds. For 9 diamonds you have to do a little more bookkeeping to account for the one bonus, as I did.

Comment: Yea except for the 8 above, I got 0.0006%, i find it hard to believe 1 diamond brings that up to 0.3?

Comment: It's actually .06 for 8, because you have to multiply by 100 to turn a fraction into a percentage.

Comment: 0.3 in my answer is already multiplied by 100. This comment section is derailing rapidly, and should not be the place to ask about how percentages work.

Comment: You multiply by 8, because of the 8 ore blocks, not 9. Result is .26%

Comment: Valid point, corrected.

Comment: I am using .4 to represent the 40% chance of getting 1, and the answer should be close to that to the 8th power or in other words 0.4 x 0.4 x 0.4 x 0.4 x 0.4 x 0.4 x 0.4 x 0.4 which equals 0.0006. That is already in percentage form, no multiplying by 100 needed. Regardless I sort of asked this question simply to brag about my luck (or lack thereof) so the question should probably just be deleted... except it wont let me because "others have spent time giving answers"

Comment: I just used your numbers to check (since everyone seems insistent that your answer is supposedly correct) and again resulted in around my number, not yours. 
So: 0.4^7 = 0.0016384 and 0.0016384 * 0.2 = 0.00032768 oh look, that is conveniently close to my answer